# select query having like and case statement in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table

```
--------------------
ID | Name | RollNO
--------------------
1  | A    | 18
--------------------
2  | B    | 19RMK2
--------------------
3  | C    | 20
--------------------
```

My second table is

```
-----------------------
OldRollNo | NewRollNo
-----------------------
18        |  18RMK1
-----------------------
19        |  19RMK2
-----------------------
20        |  20RMK3
-----------------------
21        |  21RMK4
-----------------------
22        |  22RMK5
-----------------------
```

I want the resulting table like

```
----------------------------------
ID | Name | RollNo | LatestRollNo
----------------------------------
1  | A    | 18     | 18RMK1
----------------------------------
2  | B    | 19RMK2 | 19RMK2
----------------------------------
3  | C    | 20     | 20RMK3
----------------------------------
```

What would be the select query like? This is just the replica of my problem. I have used CASE Statement with the select query but as the records in my table is large, it's taking too much time. In my second table the OldRollNo Column is unique.One more thing is that in the resultant RollNo column if the newly assigned RollNo is already present then it should be copied exactly to the next column i.e LatestRollNo. I have to check only those RollNo which are old.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select t1.ID
  , t1.Name
  , t1.RollNO
  , LatestRollNO = coalesce(n.NewRollNo, o.NewRollNo)
from t1
  left join t2 o on t1.RollNO = o.OldRollNo
  left join t2 n on t1.RollNO = n.NewRollNo
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56a30/2).

It sounds like your issue is performance not logic; something like this should hopefully allow approriate index usage assuming you have the appropriate indexes on `t2.OldRollNo` and `t2.NewRollNo`.

The problem with `OR` or `CASE` in a `WHERE` clause is that these don't always lend themselves to efficient queries; hopefully this will be a bit more useful in your case.

Comment: I liked this one. Now that's what separates the best from the rest. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use inner join.

```
SELECT t1.ID,t1.Name,t2.RollNo,t2.NewRollNo AS LatestRollNo
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.RollNo=t2.OldRollNo OR t1.RollNo=t2.NewRollNo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select f.ID, f.name, f.RollNo, s.NewRollNo as "Latest RollNo"
from FirstTable f 
inner join 
SecondTable s on f.RollNo = s.OldRollNo or f.RollNo = s.NewRollNo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.id,t.name,t.rollno,tt.newrollno as latestrollno from
talble1 t
left join
table2 tt on t.rollno = tt.oldrollno
```